# WordPress pagination returning incorrect permalinks for paged links?

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I've got a wp query loop and I have added the pagination_links function to return me the pagination. I have an issue where the link to the first page is returning me the current page instead of the link to the first page?

Can anyone see what is wrong with the below?

```
$posts_per_page = get_option('posts_per_page');
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'paged' => $paged,
);

$articles = new WP_Query( $args ); 

args = array(
    'base'               => '%_%',
    'format'             => '?paged=%#%',
    'current'            => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total'              => $articles->max_num_pages,
    'show_all'           => false,
    'end_size'           => 1,
    'mid_size'           => 1,
    'prev_next'          => true,
    'prev_text'          => __('Previous'),
    'next_text'          => __('Next'),
    'type'               => 'plain',
    'add_args'           => false,
    'add_fragment'       => '',
    'before_page_number' => '',
    'after_page_number'  => ''
);

echo paginate_links( $args );
```

Comment: In some situations you need to check for GET parameter `page` instead of `paged`, see https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Static_Front_Page and check if that applies to your situation.

Comment: Unfortunately,  changing to page causes all my pagination links to break :( All my links are correct except for the previous and the first (1) link which doesn't seem to have anything in the href for the links...